# StreamingOutput not throwing WebApplicationException, returning empty response

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

I'm having difficulty throwing a `WebApplicationException` from my `StreamingOutput` implementation. I would expect the code below to return a 501, but curl is reporting `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`. I can see the 503 in the trace of the call, but Jersey is just replying with an empty body. Does anybody know what gives?

```
public final class MyStreamingOutput implements StreamingOutput {

    @Override
    public void write(final OutputStream outputStream)
        throws IOException {

        try {
            dataProvider = new DataProvider(); // throws SQLException
        } catch (final SQLException e) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(503);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the trace I'm seeing:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid object name 'no_such_table'.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:368) ~[jtds-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
...
16:05:22.148 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.glassfish.jersey.tracing.general - MBW_WRITE_TO WriteTo by [org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.StreamingOutputProvider @1d45d135] [642.98 ms]
16:05:22.148 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.glassfish.jersey.tracing.general - WI_AFTER [org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter @77edc290 #-2147483648] AFTER context.proceed() [ 0.00 ms]
16:05:22.148 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.glassfish.jersey.tracing.general - WI_AFTER [org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor @2a0fded2 #3000] AFTER context.proceed() [ 0.01 ms]
16:05:22.148 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.glassfish.jersey.tracing.general - WI_AFTER [org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor @26c087be #10] AFTER context.proceed() [ 0.01 ms]
16:05:22.148 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.glassfish.jersey.tracing.general - WI_SUMMARY WriteTo summary: 3 interceptors [644.44 ms]
16:05:22.148 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.glassfish.jersey.tracing.general - FINISHED Response status: 200/SUCCESSFUL|OK [ ---- ms]
16:05:22.153 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.glassfish.jersey.tracing.general - EXCEPTION_MAPPING Exception mapper [com.locustec.eim.query.rest.RuntimeExceptionMapper @3a8978c7] maps [javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException @563625d0 <501/SERVER_ERROR|Not Implemented|-no-entity->] ('Carp') to <501/SERVER_ERROR|Not Implemented> [ 0.02 ms]
16:05:22.153 [http-8080-1] INFO  o.g.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter - 8 * LoggingFilter - Response received on thread http-8080-1
8 < 503

16:05:22.154 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.glassfish.jersey.tracing.general - RESPONSE_FILTER Filter by [org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter @5271b383 #-2147483648] [ 0.13 ms]
16:05:22.154 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.glassfish.jersey.tracing.general - RESPONSE_FILTER_SUMMARY Response summary: 1 filters [ 0.93 ms]
16:05:22.155 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.glassfish.jersey.tracing.general - FINISHED Response status: 501/SERVER_ERROR|Not Implemented [ ---- ms]
16:05:22.160 [http-8080-1] TRACE o.g.j.process.internal.RequestScope - [DEBUG] Released scope instance Instance{id=021c24a2-c224-4c22-8f18-e5f7f93b0295, referenceCounter=0, store size=0} on thread http-8080-1
```

Comment: Is the 501/503 mismatch a typo? I'm having the same problem, trying to map a runtime exception from a third-party library to a sensible status code - no luck yet :(

Comment: Yes, it's a typo. Either one would be fine .. just not 500, or what I'm seeing, just nothing - a totally empty response.

Answer (score 1):

Jersey is beginning the HTTP response, thus sending a 200 OK, and only after that starts calling your `StreamingOutput.write` implementation. So, when your exception is raised, it's already too late to send a different HTTP code.

The best way I found to deal with this kind of issue is trying to do as much as possible outside of the `StreamingOutput`, or in the constructor of the implementation (these versions will send 500, you can catch the `SQLException` if you want something else):

```
@GET
public StreamingOutput getDataWithAnonymousClass() throws SQLException {
    final DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider();
    return new StreamingOutput() {
        @Override
        public void write(OutputStream output) {
            dataProvider.writeData(output);
        }
    }
}


public final class MyStreamingOutput implements StreamingOutput {

    private final DataProvider dataProvider;

    public MyStreamingOutput() throws SQLException {
        this.dataProvider = new DataProvider();
    }

    @Override
    public void write(OutputStream output) {
        dataProvider.writeData(output);
    }
}

@GET
public StreamingOutput getDataWithExcInConstructor() throws SQLException {
    return new MyStreamingOutput();
}
```

That way, the exception is thrown before the HTTP response has been started, and you can have a different status.